# Migrate constraint to another size class - Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an iPhone app that already use auto layout, is there a way to migrate those constraints to any-any size and make it work for iPad?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think these WWDC sessions will be really helpful for you.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/233/

You can find the workarounds or hints for your implementing UI.

In addition, if you set the constraints correctly for the universal,
you don't need to update your origin codes about constraints.